# Combine multiple rows into one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table called `PO`, `PR`, `MR`. Each of them have **the same** `client id`, but **different** `ID`. How can I make the output something like this?

```
ID_PO   |   ID_PR    | ID_MR
1             -         -
2             -         -
3             -         -
-             A         -
-             B         -
-             C         -
-             -         I
-             -         II
-             -         III
-             -         IV
```

I've tried using JOIN, but the data appears way too much

Comment: By writing a select statement - many tutorials on-line on how to do this

Comment: @EdHeal I've tried using select and join but the data becomes way too much

Comment: Why not post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, you're probably best off using `union all`:

```
select id_po, id_pr, id_mr
from (
    select id id_po, null id_pr, null id_mr, client_id from po
    union all
    select null, id, null, client_id from pr
    union all
    select null, null, id, client_id from mr
) t
group by client_id
```

Or perhaps instead of `group by` -- `where client_id = x`...

Comment: Exactly, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your results using inner join. Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM PO
INNER JOIN PR ON PO.client_id = PR.client_id
INNER JOIN MR ON MR.client_id = PR.client_id
```

But because `INNER JOIN` is based on cartesian product, you might get multiple entries of PO and PR if the relation between tables are one-to-many.